# Angularjs search and display data in table format

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

is it possible to search data from json file and display it in a table format? ( I only want the table to show up when i hit the search button )
Would appreciate the help if someone could teach me how or give me a link as
I couldn't find it anywhere. All i can find are situations where the table is already there to begin with

Comment: you could just hide the table until that search button is pressed, if those searched links are actually helpful to you...

Comment: That'd display the whole table tho, I just want the specific result searched to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can basically make use of $filter to filter out records based on the input provided to the search box and display table only if final result has records. I have just used sample json data. In your case data would be coming from file.

```
 vm.searchData = function() {
 if (vm.searchText.length <= 0) {
   vm.finalData = [];
 }
 else{
   vm.finalData = $filter('filter')(vm.jsonData, { id: vm.searchText});
 }
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anilsarkar/f96L3zd1/39/)